# Formbuilder - form submission not updating Participant Status

Tags: civievent, formbuilder

Trying to create an Event RSVP form to allow all users (including anonymous) to update Participant Status to indicate whether they are attending or not.  I have added Statuses (invited, will attend, will not attend).  All invitees are added to the event and set to 'invited'.

**The form details...**

- Form permissions set open to all users [Generic: All users (including anonymous)] and exposed to front-end and page route is set.
- It contains three tabs (Participant1, Individual1, Event1).  All security is Form-based.
- All tabs are set to 'Allowed Action' = Update, and 'Accept ID from URL' = Yes.
- ParticipantID, IndividualID, and EventID are passed via URL and prepopulate the form correctly.
- On the form layout - [Event Title] and [Contact first and last name] are display only.
- Participant Status is exposed as checklist, but limited to two responses [I will attend] or [I will not attend].

**What happens...**

- I call the form using a URL with the applicable event, contact, and participant id and the form populates correctly.
- I check a box to indicate [I will attend] and click Submit.
- An empty semi-opaque gray box appears overlayed on the form while the wheel spins.
  After a moment, the submission states 'Saved'.

**The problem...**

- The Status on the Participant record doesn't actually update.  What am I doing wrong?
- Also, if I can get that working: How can I limit the form to only apply to that Event.  I don't care that anonymous users are updating their own status for this event, but don't want the URL to be manipulated to allow users to update other events.

Any insight great appreciated.  Happy to provide additional info as needed.